# How to get touchscreen right click on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: touchscreen, raspbian-stretch

I am currently using Raspbian Stretch with a [Waveshare 7 inch touchscreen](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)), and I would like to get right click input (preferably with two finger or long touch).

There appear to be no solutions for Raspbian Stretch, and I have tried to use solutions which have worked on previous versions of Raspbian (like Jessie and Wheezy) such as using [twofing](http://plippo.de/p/twofing) or [modifying the `xorg.conf` file](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121602) to get the right click menu, but none work.

However, I found that in only Chromium, two finger touch and long press both make the right click menu come up, but when I do it on the desktop/anywhere else, nothing happens.

Any suggestions on how to get right click input from the touchscreen would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @vtni Unfortunately I haven't found a solution so far :(

Comment: on my screen (elegoo mini 4,7 inch), as I remember i did double click or just press for few seconds

Comment: Trying twofinger with a Waveshare 7 inch touchscreen without success... Tablet interface would be really nice. And double touch is a mouse click instead of single touch.

Comment: While your twofing implementations are in place, do you have a mouse and keyboard plugged into USB?  I've read somewhere that sometimes this will kill the twofing function.. having the mouse and keyboard plugged in.

Comment: As a wild shot, try `apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch`

Answer (score 1):

In general input-related options from `xorg.conf` are given to [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml), so unless you know which options will work and want to make permanent changes to configuration, it's better to run `xinput` directly rather than repeatedly changing `xorg.conf` and restarting X.

Run `xinput list` to find the touchscreen ID, then `xinput list-props <ID>` to find the relevant property (usually `EmulateThirdButton`). Then try to enable that property for the touchscreen and see if that helps. If not, try to do the same with the next input device in the hierarchy, up to the `Virtual core pointer`.